# Is there some way I can get a $index when I have an ng-repeat inside an ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

My application used to have this code:

```
<div ng-click="getQuestion(q.number)
     ng-repeat="q in qs">{{ q.number }}</div>
```

It very simply displayed `<div>`s with each containing a question number and it had a click event. There were also 5-6 other uses of the `q` within each repeat but to simplify I'm just showing this above.

Now I was asked to change this into a CSS:table that consists of 5 rows with each row having ten columns. To do this I used two ng-repeats with one inside the other like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">
   <div ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
      <div ng-click="getQuestion(qs[i * 10 + j + 1].number)">
        {{ qs[i * 10 + j + 1].number }}  
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The formula :  `qs[i * 10 + j + 1]` gives me the same as I was getting before with `q`.

However within that middle  I need to access qs[i * 10 + j + 1] many times
and so this formula appears in many different places.

Is there some way using ng-repeat or something else that I could simplify 
this. I read about $index but in this case I need something like an $index that gives me the position from the outer loop.

Comment: how about ng-init, `ng-init='row=qs[i * 10 + j + 1]'`

Comment: So you are in a ng-repeat and want the $index of the outer ng-repeat? Did you try to use $parent.$index?

Comment: @HimmetAvsar - I know how to get the index of the outer repeat. In my case this is just the value of j.  What I want to do is to somehow simplify the way I get the question number inside the inner loop so it's not a formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ng-init

```
<div ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">
    <div ng-repeat="j in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]" ng-init="row=qs[i * 10 + j + 1]'">
          <div ng-click="getQuestion(row.number)">
            {{ row.number }}  
          </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: My solution gives me 50 cells but I think yours will only give 10.  Am I correct ?

Comment: what you should take from the answer is that, `you can use ng-init with ng-repeat to create new variables`, that's the suggested way to do it...

Comment: you can always fine tune `a*b+c` parts to get it work the way you want

Comment: Okay I see what you mean now. If you don't mind can you add in the additional <div> with the indexing of I, like I have in my question because I think that would make it a bit clear to other. Thanks

Comment: @Alan : added the div as suggested

Comment: Thanks for the changes. I already accepted the answer. But out of interest, could I also put the ng-init on the inner div?  Thanks

Comment: ofcourse you can... ng-init should be used with ng-repeat, suggested way.. and thats with any ng-repeat, so no doubt about inner/outer etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) for this. It allows you to define an alias for a value - which in this case could be the outer index. The doc has a very similar example.